# Calculating confidence intervals for non-linear model: Error in predictNLS

Tags: r

I want the two-sided 95% confidence interval for my non-linear model. I used the following data:

```
xvalues<-c(0.92 , 3.00,  6.00 , 9.00 ,12.00 ,15.00, 18.00, 21.00, 24.00, 27.00)
yvalues<-c(210000000 ,210000000 ,200000000 ,180000000, 180000000, 180000000 ,160000000, 160000000 ,160000000, 150000000)
data<-data.frame(xvalues,yvalues)
```

I fitted an asymptotic model to the data:

```
fit = nls(yvalues ~ SSasymp(xvalues, Asym, r0, lrc), data=data)
xCurve <- seq(0, 27, 1)
yCurve <- coef(fit)[1]+(coef(fit)[2]-coef(fit)[1])*exp(-exp(coef(fit)[3])*xCurve)
plot(yvalues~xvalues)   
lines(xCurve, yCurve, col = 'green', lty = 1)
```

I want confidence lines around my regression line. Unfortunately I got this error, when I wanted to predict the confidence interval:

```
xnew<-seq(0,27,1)
pre<-predictNLS(fit, newdata=data.frame(xvalues=xnew), interval = c("confidence"),alpha = 0.05)

predictNLS: Propagating predictor value #1...

Error in if (df != as.integer(df)) stop("Rejection sampling currenly works only for integer degrees of freedom. Consider using algorithm='gibbs'.") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I also tried it with `pre<-predictNLS(fit, newdata=data.frame(xvalues=xnew), interval = c("confidence"),alpha = 0.05,algorithm='gibbs')`, but I got the same Error. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Should clarify that `predictNLS` is from the `propagate` library, right? The code works fine for me. No error. Perhaps try updating `propagate`?

Comment: Yes, I used the propagate library. I updated propagate, but I get still the error.